# Get full details of what is using memory in PHP

Tags: php, memory

I have a PHP script that is failing with a fatal out-of-memory error.  It is a script that processes all records in the DB - it works fine up to about 10k records and then hits the memory error.

However, I can't find out what is using up my application's memory.

I've checked the `$_GLOBALS` array and that accounts for maybe 1 MB or so.

I've checked the call stack at various points and have seen nothing unexpected.

The base memory requirement for PHP plus all relevant class files, etc. is about 7MB.

My feeling is that there is probably somewhere in the code that is resulting in variable references persisting - either deliberately (e.g. via a static cache in some class or other) or by mistake (e.g. resource handles not being freed).

Obviously functions like `memory_get_usage()` can tell me how much memory is used at any given point in the script, and tracking this is a slow but effective way of debugging.  However, is there any way of getting details about what is actually using that memory?

Happy to accept answers that use an external tool (e.g. XDebug) providing they give useful output (i.e. output that identifies the class/variable names rather than using PHPs internal IDs).  The output I expect would be something like you get from `var_dump`/`print_r`.

[Note that this question is not about how to debug out-of-memory issues in general, but specifically about whether there is a way to expose the details of memory use when debugging.]

Comment: On first glance, this looks promising!  Any reason you posted this as a comment, rather than an answer?

Comment: That's the spirit! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paul Crovella provided a link, but couldn't be bothered to post it as an answer, so I'm doing it for him.

The php-memprof extension (https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler) provides a number of tools that can be used to provide exactly the information that the question asks for.

From the readme file:

> php-memprof profiles memory usage of PHP scripts, and especially can tell which function has allocated every single byte of memory currently allocated.
>
> Memprof can be enabled during script execution by calling memprof_enable().
>
> Then the memory usage can be dumped by calling one of the memprof_dump_ functions. Both tell which functions allocated all the currently allocated memory.

The original question asked for something like `print_r()`, and this is provided by the `memprof_dump_array()` function.  However, there are a number of other ways of accessing the memory profile which may be more useful depending on what you are trying to achieve, including dumping the entire memory map in callgrind format, for offline analysis.

As it is a PHP extension, it will require access to php.ini in order to install it, so it may not be suitable for debugging issues on live sites (but nobody does that, right?).