# CakePHP 2.10: memory leak while looping and using Cache::read()

Tags: php, loops, caching, cakephp, memory-leaks

I'm executing a loop where I need to render 1,500 CSVs one at a time and write the results to one concatenation file, one by one. To do this I am running some model methods that involve pulling each single cached CSV out of my file cache engine using the native CakePHP Cache helper.

What's strange is that even if the cached data I'm reading is relatively small in size, the memory usage periodically ticks up by about 2MB and garbage collection never happens to ever bring it back down. I've tried running `Cache::gc($cache_config)` and `gc_collect_cycles()` to mitigate this, but they seem to do nothing.

Below is just **one loop iteration** as an example. Memory usage just keeps growing and growing. It ticks up in this way about every 2-3 loop iterations (i.e. not every time, which is even more maddening.)

```
## memory_get_usage(true) is 134MB

$data = Cache::read($cache_key,$cache_config);

## strlen(serialize($data)) is 87KB

## memory_get_usage(true) is 136MB
```

Is there a solution or a workaround?

Comment: There's insufficient code in the question to say what's happening. There's an implied misunderstanding that the only thing consuming memory with that call is the size of `$data` - that's probably not true. You may find it helpful to [profile memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43955172/761202) to see what's consuming ram, you can also set the memory limit to just above current usage and from the OOM exception see what is attempting to consume ram.

Comment: This might be related to this PHP bug related to running unserialize() (which Cache::read() does when using FileEngine): https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81142   -- I tested the small example there and am seeing the leak in my script (even though I'm using PHP 7.2).